# Property Does not exist despite null coalescing and optional chaining

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

I have a piece of code on which I do optional chaining and also null coalescing.

I don't understand why it still complains about property not existing as shown in the image below

The error message is

```
TS2339: Property 'drawer' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

```
export const AppBar = styled(BaseAppBar, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "open",
})<AppBarProps>(({ theme }) => ({
  zIndex: theme?.zIndex?.drawer ?? 2,
}));

AppBar.defaultProps = {
  color: "primary",
};
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ueuR.png)

Comment: Typescript is strict so if you did not declare `drawer` into your `zIndex` `type/interface`, it will complain despite having it on optional chaining. So did you declare it in your type?

Comment: @JkAlombro zIndex is coming from 3rd party lib, material UI, and it is documented to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says `'drawer' does not exist on type '{}'`, that's mean the `zIndex` has the type of empty object, you need to define the type of `zIndex` inside the `theme` globally or use `as` to do type assertion.

```
export const AppBar = styled(BaseAppBar, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "open",
})<AppBarProps>(({ theme }) => ({
  zIndex: (theme?.zIndex as { drawer: number }).drawer ?? 2,
}));
```